# Verify OpenSSL s/mime signature using C code

Tags: c, openssl

I have C based applications ,they are signed with openssl smime.

I am looking to validate those s/mime signature using OpenSSL programmatically using C. I have spent lot of time in searching similar scenario,but didn't get relevant page.

I have downloaded (openssl-1.0.2a) and compiled on linux env. I have integrated compiled static library to my project as well.

Please let me know how to proceed now for signature verification OR please guide me which API I need to call to verify s/mime signature.

Answer (score 1):

If you already compiled OpenSSL from source it means that you can look at: `<your-openssl-source-dir>/demos/smime` which shows you how to use the `PKCS7_*` family of functions, but I think that **more useful** would be to look at the `CMS_*` family see: `<your-openssl-source-dir>/demos/cms`. These examples probably show much more than you need.

Comment: Thanks.I am able to progress now. I have a follow up question here:

In openssl-1.0.2a/demos/smime/smver.c
    tbio = BIO_new_file("cacert.pem", "r");
its trying to read cacert.pem file which includes certificate and private key both and creates BIO object while in my case two separate files are there one for .key and second .crt file.
How to read these two files and create BIO objects ?

Answer (score 1):

Now I am able to verify the smime signature using openssl PKCS7_verify API.

```
int PKCS7_verify(PKCS7 *p7, STACK_OF(X509) *certs, X509_STORE *store, BIO *indata, BIO *out, int flags);
```

More details can be found here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS7_verify.html